# Transferring from event rate to probability density

Tags: probability, sampling

Suppose I have a function $N(x)$ defined on an interval $[x_1,x_2]$, which the derivative $\frac{dN}{dx}$ describes the rate of events, i.e. the number of events per unit $x$. Suppose that $\frac{dN}{dx} = Cx^{\gamma}$ where $C$ is a constant, $\gamma\neq-1$. Then if we define $y = x^{\gamma+1}$, then $\frac{dN}{dy} = \widetilde{C}$ which is constant. That is, the event rate in $y$-space is constant.

I want to randomly sample events in $x$-space according to the above event rate. If my interval is $[x_1,x_2]$ in $x$-space, then my guess for distribution of events in $y$-space will be uniform in $[y(x_1),y(x_2)]$ (or the other way around if $\gamma<0$). So, basically I want to uniformly sample in $[y(x_1),y(x_2)]$ and deduce from this about the sampling in $x$-space. How can I do that, taking into account the value of $\widetilde{C}$?

Comment: do not know the answer, but dN/dy = 0

Comment: @user1700890 Let's see, if $\frac{dN}{dx} = Cx^{\gamma}$, then $N(x) = (\gamma + 1)Cx^{\gamma+1} = (\gamma+1)Cy\Rightarrow \frac{dN}{dy} = (\gamma+1)C = \widetilde{C}$